# 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, find

I know this is a basic question, but I'm new to python and can't figure out how to solve it.

I have a list like the next example:

```
entities = ["#1= IFCORGANIZATION($,'Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)',$,$,$)";, "#5= IFCAPPLICATION(#1,'2014','Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)','Revit');"]
```

My problem is how to add the information from the list `"entities"` to a dictionary in the following format:

```
dic = {'#1= IFCORGANIZATION' : ['$','Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)','$','$','$'], '#5= IFCAPPLICATION' : ['#1','2014','Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)','Revit']
```

I tried to do this using `"find"` but I'm getting the following error:
 `'list' object has no attribute 'find'`,

and I don't know how to do this without find method.

Comment: Do you mean `'$'` instead of `$`?

Comment: Well, lists don't *have* a `find()` method. They do have an `index()` method, though.

Comment: zhangxaochen: That's correct. I'm sorry for my mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to deal with strings. First split each element string with `'('`, with maxsplit being 1:

```
In [48]: dic=dict(e[:-1].split('(', 1) for e in entities) #using [:-1] to filter out ')'
    ...: print dic
    ...: 
{'#5= IFCAPPLICATION': "#1,'2014','Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)','Revit')", '#1= IFCORGANIZATION': "$,'Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)',$,$,$)"}
```

then split each value in the dict with `','`:

```
In [55]: dic={k: dic[k][:-1].split(',') for k in dic}
    ...: print dic
{'#5= IFCAPPLICATION': ['#1', "'2014'", "'Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)'", "'Revit'"], '#1= IFCORGANIZATION': ['$', "'Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)'", '$', '$', '$']}
```

Note that the key-value pairs in a dict is unordered, as you may see `'#1= IFCORGANIZATION'` is not showing in the first place.

Comment: zhangxaochen: Many thanks for your support. I tried your code and it really does what I need. I dont need the dictionary to be in a specific order so that's not a problem. Thank you for the explation too. Regards!

Answer (score 14):

If you want to know if a value is in a list you can use `in`, like this:

```
>>> my_list = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> "two" in my_list
True
>>>
```

If you need to get the position of the value in the list you must use `index`:

```
>>> my_list.index("two")
1
>>>
```

Note that the first element of the list has the 0 index.

Comment: Trimax: Thank you for the support. The problem is that the data in the list is always diferent and consequently I can't search for a specific word. I need to divide each string in the list, in the format presented before, so that I can manipulate the information and then use it.

Comment: For search pattern in strings is more useful the Regular Expressions module `re` https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html and you can extract them by groups in a list.

Comment: @Trimax your right, but a list comprehension will be more appropiate. If the so don't know how to iterate over a list, you think it will be ok with re ?

Comment: with re.findall() you get a list with all mathes in the string and your input seems has a pattern, the data in the list is always diferent but it isn't ramdom.

Comment: @Trimax In my particular case I don't mind if the dictionary isn't in a correct order. But if i need so, I will use your sugestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
>>> import re
>>> import ast
>>> entities = ["#1= IFCORGANIZATION('$','Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)','$','$','$');", "#5= IFCAPPLICATION('#1','2014','Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)','Revit');"]
>>> entities = [a.strip(';') for a in entities]
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\((.*)\)')
>>> dic = {}
>>> for a in entities:
...     s = re.search(pattern, a)
...     dic[a[:a.index(s.group(0))]] = list(ast.literal_eval(s.group(0)))
>>> dic
{'#5= IFCAPPLICATION': ['#1', '2014', 'Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)', 'Revit'], '#1= IFCORGANIZATION': ['$', 'Autodesk Revit 2014 (ENU)', '$', '$', '$']}
```

This regex `r'\((.*)\)'` looks for elements in `(` and `)` and converts them to a list. It makes the sub string appearing before the brackets as the key and the list as the value.

Comment: shaktimaan: Thank you for your quick support. I didn't know those modules, so thank you  for introducing me to them. I didn't manage to get your code to work because in my "entities" variable I don't have the ' along with the $, i.e. '$'. But I think with  a few ajustments it will wotk fine! Regards.

Comment: Without the quotes it will get a little complicated to store them as a list

Comment: @ shaktimaan: The zhangxaochen answer doesn't use any modules but it works just fine! Thank you.